# Using Range.End without using .select

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know if this is possible, but I hereby call upon you VBA masters for some help.

To summarize: I am appending a formula to a table via VBA, which populates the entire column, and then attempting to copy and paste values to the same column,(It varies in size, hence why the .End(XlDown) (Ideally without using select as it slows the VBA down))

I have no issue using:

```
Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P2", Range("P2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

But, by using this, I need to have the sheet ("Cancelations Temp") selected, if it is not, I get an application-defined error.

Is there a way for me to basically achieve this (copying a column that changes sizes on each run of the macro), without using a select method?

I supposed I could see where the range end each time, define it as a variable (Say Var), and then do it via:

```
Sheets("SheetName").Range("P2:Var").Copy
Sheets("SheetName").Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I hope I haven't messed up the formating... I probably have though, will try and fix once I see how it came out

This is my current code:

```
Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP([@[Policy Number]],Temp_Cancelations,6,FALSE)=""MTC"",""Canceled"",IF(VLOOKUP([@[Policy Number]],Temp_Cancelations,6,FALSE)=""MTR"",""Reinstated"",""Not Canceled"")),"""")"
    'Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Select
    Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P2", Range("P2").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

When run within the Sheet mentioned, I get no issues and all is correct.
When I run it from the main page (Where the user would run the macro from), I get an application or object defined error. When I run it with the Select method (Commented in the code above), it runs fine, but goes to the sheet in question.

Thanks in advance, I have searched around for this, but no resolution was found.

Comment: Your last code is using a formula on P2 then paste it's values to the whole column, is that your goal?

Comment: Hi, Yes, correct. It uses a formula on P2, which is a table so it populates it until the end of the table (so the whole column), and I am attempting to paste this column to the same column, but as values. The column varies in length. Sorry if my explanation is not the best!

Comment: You could just use `Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P:P").Value = Sheets("Cancelations Temp").Range("P:P").Value` this will turn the whole column into values. I'd suggest to also reference the workbook besides the worksheet. You can use `Worksheet` and `Workbook` variables.

Comment: Wouldn't that select the whole column and make my table infinite? I am going to attempt this now. Edit: You are completely correct, I do not know why I did not try this initially... I feel stupid! It keeps my table size the same, and only copies the values within the range. Thank you very much! I should have attempted the simple way first, didnt even think of it!

Comment: Thanks again Damian, much appreciated, super fast response!!!! And sorry for the formatting issues! (And I will be adding references to the workbook also)

Comment: There are better ways.. but this is fast and reliable. You could set a range by calculating the last row on your table and then do the same only within that range.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of going that route if I didnt find another way (It's silly, but I hate calculating last rows, and setting range via variables), but your suggestion is ideal, I don't know why I assumed it would mess up table ranges. You learn something new everyday (And I feel a little dumb when it is such a simple thing!) Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses your suggested approach:

```
Sub KopyPaste()
    Dim N As Long, rng As Range
    With Sheets("Cancelations Temp")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("P2:P" & N)
        rng.Copy
        rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

As an alternative to `Copy / PasteSpecial`:

```
Sub KopyPaste()
    Dim N As Long, rng As Range
    With Sheets("Cancelations Temp")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("P2:P" & N)
        rng.Value = rng.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student! Much appreciated, just as Damian mentioned above, I was resigning myself to not do it via a variable and calculating last row, but I just have to not be lazy and do it, much nicer. And not using copy / paste is defenitely less resource intensive, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, to only turn the range you need:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cancelations Temp") 'using this you avoid the need to reference it again between the With
        .Range("P2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP([@[Policy Number]],Temp_Cancelations,6,FALSE)=""MTC"",""Canceled"",IF(VLOOKUP([@[Policy Number]],Temp_Cancelations,6,FALSE)=""MTR"",""Reinstated"",""Not Canceled"")),"""")"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row 'easy way to calculate the last row
        .Range("P2", .Cells(LastRow, "P")).Value = .Range("P2", .Cells(LastRow, "P")).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm assuming the workbook you are working is the one holding the code, hence the `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much, I might as well code it in properly now that I have the method, so two things learnt today!
Thanks again Damian, amazing help!